# Adding New GTM Tags Disables Registration button of ecommerce site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing the issue when adding new GTM tag in some of my pages which already have one GTM tag enabled and we want to add one more new GTM tag.

Also tried to add Google Optimize, CrazyEgg and Mouseflow instead of new GTM tag.

But it gives an error of jQuery is not defined and blocks jQuery when clicking on Register button.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Wait, you added a tag in HTML and now you getting that jQ is not defined? If you remove it it's oke? Have you by any chance messes with loading order of external js/libs/frameworks  files in index.html?

Comment: Hello @DanteTheSmith,
Here, I used HTML twig file which already having one GTM in the enabled state.
Basically, I want to add new GTM tag into it. But it blocks jQuery and gives the error when any click event occurs such as Register, Checkout etc.